# Setting Custom Cluster Icon with Picture Marker Symbols using ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, clustering, feature-layer

**Problem**:
Unsure how to set a custom icon for the cluster symbol, not the individual points or even the label of the cluster but the symbology for the cluster icon itself.

**Context**:
A Feature Layer is being rendered by unique value with picture marker symbols for each value. When [clustering is applied](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-FeatureReductionCluster.html) it picks one of the PictureMarkerSymbols to use as the symbology for the cluster point itself. I would like to have a completely different symbol for the cluster itself.

Is there a way to customise the cluster icon?

***TLDR:* Esri Leaflet seems to accomplish exactly what I am describing** (see link and gif):
https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/styling-clusters.html
Is the cluster symbol being different from the feature symbol possible to do in the ESRI JS API?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cluster symbol depends on the feature layer symbol, take a look at the examples an explanation of the API documentation, styles and configuration section.

[ArcGIS API - FeatureReductionCluster](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-support-FeatureReductionCluster.html)

> While this can be thought of as a visualization technique, clustering is actually a method of reducing features in the view. It is therefore independent of the Renderer. The style, labels, and popup of each cluster summarizes the features it represents.

Personally, I think it makes sense. This because it is actually showing a group of features, so naturally the cluster symbology should somehow depend on the features that are grouped.

Comment: Given that featureReduction seems to do a calculation and select the most common feature, there might have been a way to intercept that / modify that and point to a different graphic to display? 

If not, is there a way where what I described could be performed without using featureReduction? E.g. using multiple layers or something?

Comment: Yeah I think that could be one way to achieve it .. Another could be the disable feature reduction at a certain zoom level and have two symbols one for the upper levels an one for the lower levels .. What exactly you have in mind? what you want to achieve?